# How to fix the camera auto-position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a first-person shooting controller. When I position the camera to a certain position, it auto-positions itself to the middle of the character, and moving it just resets it to its default position.

I have tried moving the camera so that it is in the correct position, however, it auto-corrects itself to be in the middle of the character. I have tried creating a serialized field for the camera so that I can assign a camera manually. However, this did not fix the issue.

[image: image of auto camera positioning]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class Shooter_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform shootingPosition;
    public Transform aimDownSightsPosition;
    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

    public float shootingRate = 0.1f;
    public float bulletSpeed = 10f;

    public float aimDownSightsSpeed = 5f;
    public float defaultFov = 90f;

    private float shootingTimer = 0f;

    private bool isAiming = false;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        shootingTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        //Shooting mechanic

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && shootingTimer > shootingRate)
        {
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, shootingPosition.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(mainCamera.transform.forward));
            Rigidbody bulletRigidBody = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            bulletRigidBody.velocity = mainCamera.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
            shootingTimer = 0f;
        }

        //Aiming mechanic 

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire2"))
        {
            isAiming = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isAiming = false;
        }

        if (isAiming)
        {
            mainCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(mainCamera.fieldOfView, defaultFov / 2f, aimDownSightsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            mainCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(mainCamera.transform.localPosition, aimDownSightsPosition.localPosition, aimDownSightsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            mainCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(mainCamera.fieldOfView, defaultFov, aimDownSightsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            mainCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(mainCamera.transform.localPosition, Vector3.zero, aimDownSightsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
mainCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(mainCamera.transform.localPosition, Vector3.zero, aimDownSightsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

If not aiming, it lerps camera local position to `Vector3.zero`, which is the local origin of the parent object.